# how to sort months(used to categorise) taken from database column using sql query

Tags: mysql

In one of my project I am grouping my data based on month name as January, February. In front page I want a drop down with only the name of  months present in database and I want in order as January, February.How do i get this using sql query.

```
$res = $this->db->query('SELECT date FROM tbl_name WHERE category_id="'.$data->category_id.'" GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC')->result_array();
```

here, date is column name in database which stores name of month,
$data->category_id is some specific value

Any help and/or suggestions is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the format of date in your table?

Comment: i only store the name of month in date as january, february and so on,not the full date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Overlooked `%M` in the manual. It works this way:

```
ORDER BY month(str_to_date(`date`, '%M'))
```

**end of update**

You can have a try with

```
ORDER BY month(str_to_date(`date`, '%b'))
```

Although this just worked for me with 'Jan' for example, not with 'January'.

The other way which works for sure but is a bit more clumsy is

```
ORDER BY CASE `date` 
WHEN 'January' THEN 1
WHEN 'February' THEN 2
...
ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: `%b` is for `Jan, Feb,..`. I think you mean `%M`

Comment: @tombom thanks bdw JW is correct, should be %M.
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm